# Not getting refund on my credit card from a student accomodation

Tags: contract-law, consumer-protection, ireland

I am a Spanish post-grad who is doing an internship at a company in Dublin. I booked an accommodation with a student accommodation agency located in Dublin.

They asked for a full year deposit even though I was only booking for 3 months. When I get there the room was full of rubbish, vomit on the carpet, WiFi not working, shower not working properly, several knives stabbed on the walls...

I worked full time from Monday to Friday, waking at 6:30 AM and returning at 8:00 PM. Not a single day could I get my daily rest due to my "kind" roommates who partied every single day. I sent lots of email to the company, asking to get a room change. Time passed without reply, then I started to call to their contact phone and got no response. I finally decided to end the accommodation. They told me that they were sorry and that I would get my money back within 6 days.

3 weeks have passed and I have not seen any money.  I keep calling but they always say that they will call me back with the details etc... Are there any legal ways to get my money back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you paid with a credit card you should simple demand a "chargeback" (a.k.a. "dispute") of their original charge.  Provide your argument and evidence to your credit card issuer.  The burden then falls on the seller to establish that they are entitled to the money charged.